# Use of XML / XML Attributes in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I am new to XML and XML attributes. I have read in some XML documentation that XML can be represented in 2 ways:

Method-1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Method - 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD TITLE="Empire Burlesque" ARTIST="Bob Dylan" COUNTRY="USA" COMPANY="Columbia" PRICE="10.90" YEAR="1985"/>
    <CD TITLE="Hide your heart" ARTIST="Bonnie Tyler" COUNTRY="UK" COMPANY="CBS Records" PRICE="8.90" YEAR="1988"/>
 </CATALOG>
```

But for example when I am using this function to filter where price >=9 and display the data in a grid.
    When using XML Way 1, it works fine, but when I use XML Way 2, the datagrid is empty. Also note that I am using @ Binding at the datafield of each DatagridColumn. My filter function is as such:

```
private function myFilter(xml:XML):Boolean
            {
                return Number(xml.PRICE) >= 9;
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In way number 2, the price is an atribute and not a subtag so it should be accessed with the @ symobl.

So for way 2, your filter function should be:

```
private function myFilter(xml:XML):Boolean
            {
                return Number(xml.@PRICE) >= 9;
            }
```

Notice the @ before PRICE.

Comment: Holy Man! I missed that completely..How dumb from my part. Thanks